# Angular4 How can I call service method in closure

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to use a service object in callback method. I get undefined error when I use the service in callback method. How can I solve it?

send.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { ExampleService } from '../../services/example.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'example',
  templateUrl: './send.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./send.component.css']
})
export class SendComponent {
  public exampleService = null

  constructor(private service: ExampleService) {
    this.exampleService = service
  }

  submit() {
    function postSendTransactionCallback(result) {
      console.log(this.exampleService); // exampleService is undefined
    }

    this.exampleService.postSendTransaction(this.data, postSendTransactionCallback); // This is no problem
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Arrow `function` while defining `postSendTransactionCallback`

```
submit() {
    let postSendTransactionCallback = (result) => {
      console.log(this.exampleService);
    }
    this.exampleService.postSendTransaction(this.data, postSendTransactionCallback);
}
```

---

Use `.bind(this)` like below without changing `postSendTransaction` method

```
this.exampleService.postSendTransaction(
  this.data, postSendTransactionCallback.bind(this)
);
```

Comment: Thank you. You saved me. I'll accept your answer in 2 min.

Answer (score 1):

User arrow function because [javascript arrow(=>) function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) bind the scope with it where it is defined:

```
 submit() {
    this.exampleService.postSendTransaction(this.data, (result) => {
      console.log(this.exampleService); // 
    }); 
  }
```